# Ember data - change model URL

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember 2.0 and ember-data 2.0, and I have been struggling to find a way to pass custom URL to model.

For example, if my model is named `Person` and stored in model/person.js file, I would like rest web service url for finding record to be `xxx/user/1`, or in other words to avoid convention, and pass my URL to rest service - is is possible at all?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Adapter.

If your backend conventions differ from Ember Data convention, it easy to change its functionality by swapping out or extending the default Adapter.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/v1',
  pathForType: function(type) {
    return Ember.Inflector.inflector.singularize(type);
  }
});
```

If you want just override a specific model just write new adapter with `modelName + Adapter`.
When I want to use a custom adapter for a 'note' model I can do something like:

```
App.Note = DS.Model.extend({
   title: DS.attr('string'),
   /* others attrs */
});

App.NoteAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'other/endpoint',
  pathForType: function(type) {
   return Ember.Inflector.inflector.pluralize(type);
  }
});
```

Take a look at [ember adapter guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_path-customization), if you use ember-cli use blueprint generator like:

`ember generate adapter user`

Comment: Thanks! I guess that in pathForType method I should read a map that will contain type/path pairs, where I could map Ember types to url paths on my backend server?

Comment: it is not necessary, you can use Adapter for specific model.

Comment: I think you can also override RESTAdapter.buildURL method to adjust ember-data to any form of your API.