# Different access name for same model in Ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

i have a model in ember , called "post" ,so when i use store to get/delete data the request will be "/post" , is it possible to have another namespace like "/tenant" to access same model post ?

like post.delete() should send DELETE backend response as "/tenant/#id" instead of "/post/#id" . i am changing my backend api so want to change the frontend end point without changing the model name in frontend ,

Comment: So you want to change `post` to be `tenant`?  Or do you want both to exist?

Comment: in backend api it is changed to tenant , but in frontend i dont want to my model/post.js to be renamed . i want to change the endpoint to "/tenant" when hitting the post model @RockwellRice

Comment: so you want all routes that use `post/` to use `tenant/` instead?

Comment: yes that is all needed. @RockwellRice

Comment: When you say routes are you talking about the routes in your ember app or in Rails?

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat answered here [Ember data - change model URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113494/ember-data-change-model-url) but the Ember version there is quite old.

Anyways I guess you should use a custom adapter for a type like this
`ember g adapter post`, and then you just override the `pathForType`:

```
import ApplicationAdapter from './application';

export default class PostAdapter extends ApplicationAdapter {
  pathForType() {
    return "tenant"; // or is it tenants?
  }
}
```

Comment: It's also covered in the [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.24.0/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_path-customization), though they show an application-level adapter rather than a model-specific adapter.